# foreign keys not adding instead giving errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL

my database created is like this:

```
Create table Author ( Id int , Name nvarchar(max) );

Create table Image ( Id int ,ImagePath nvarchar(max) );

Create table Blog ( Id int ,Name nvarchar(max) ,AuthorId int );

Create table BlogImages ( Id int ,BlogId int ,ImageId int );
```

now when I am trying this below part I am getting errors

```
ALTER TABLE Blog ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuthorId) REFERENCES Author(Id)

ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD FOREIGN KEY (BlogId) REFERENCES Blog(Id)

ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD FOREIGN KEY (ImageId) REFERENCES Image(Id)
```

Please guide 
I need to add foreign keys to my tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `primary keys`:

```
Create table Author 
 ( 
    Id int , 
    Name nvarchar(max), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
 );

Create table Image
  ( 
    Id int ,
    ImagePath nvarchar(max), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  )

Create table Blog 
  ( 
    Id int ,
    Name nvarchar(max) ,
    AuthorId int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
   );

 Create table BlogImages 
  ( 
     Id int ,
     BlogId int ,
     ImageId int 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  );
```

or this way:

```
ALTER TABLE Author ADD PRIMARY KEY  Author(Id);
ALTER TABLE Image ADD PRIMARY KEY  Image(Id);
ALTER TABLE Blog ADD PRIMARY KEY  Blog(Id);
ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD PRIMARY KEY  BlogImages(Id);
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70610/2/0)

you can also create constraint primary key, this is a way I prefer

```
ALTER TABLE Author ADD CONSTRAINT pk_AuthorID PRIMARY KEY (ID); 
ALTER TABLE Image ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ImageID PRIMARY KEY (ID) ;
ALTER TABLE Blog ADD CONSTRAINT pk_BlogID PRIMARY KEY (ID); 
ALTER TABLE BlogImages ADD CONSTRAINT pk_BlogImagesID PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  add query to create table

```
CREATE TABLE author ( Id int , Name varchar(255) );
```

When you  want alter Author table  then you can write  the below query

```
ALTER TABLE author ADD test varchar(255)
```

When you want to add  primary key to id you can put  below query

```
ALTER TABLE author ADD Primary key author(Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can either add a primary key or unique key constraint on columns
>   on the parent tables to be used in your query.